# ¿Cómo deshabilitar el boton de upload y preview details de al archivo cargado?

Tags: jquery, fileupload, bootstrap-file-input

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo deshabilitar los botones de `Upload File` y `View Details` del archivo adjunto. Estoy usando
fileinput del siguiente repositorio https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución, este era la opción que permite deshabilitar las opciones del archivo adjunto.

```
"fileActionSettings": {
                "showUpload": false,
                "showZoom": false
            }
```